# c++ Any type of array as an argument for a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I tried to make a function that takes a vector for an argument:

```
class class0
{
   ...
   ...
}
void function (vector <class0> random_vector)
{
   ...
   ...
}
int main ()
{
   vector <class0> the_vector;
   function (the_vector);
   ...
   ...
}
```

It worked. I achieved it with a simple experiment. But I don't know if there is more to know about doing something like this. Is it the same with the other types of arrays? Is this the best way?

So I need is more info about using any type of arrays as an argument for a function.

Comment: You should pass your vector by reference.

Comment: Use references, even more const ones if you won't modify the vector

Comment: @Cicada: Without knowing what `function` does, you do not have enough information to determine that.

Comment: The vector is a class, not an array. Yes this class represents an array, but what is there to be known for passing vector as an argument is similar for all classes containing dunamically allocated members.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use templates:

```
template <typename T>
void function (const vector<T>& random_vector)
{
}
```

which you call like this:

```
vector<A> vecA;
vector<int> vecI;
function(vecA);
function(vecI);
```

#### After re-reading your question, I see you're more interested in different types of containers.

This can also be achieved with templates:

```
template <typename container>
void function2 (const container& random_vector)
{
}
```

which you can call like so:

```
list<A> lA;
vector<int> li;
function2 (lA);
function2 (li);
```

Also, you should pass vector types by `const &` for optimization purposes.

Comment: Thank you! Can I have an example, so I can understand it better?

Comment: The example depends on what you want to achieve. Actually, this code was an example (at least that was the intention). You have something compilable on which you can build.